# how to download the pdfbox-app jar?

Tags: apache, maven, pdfbox, snapshot

I'm working with pdfbox-app-2.0.0-20140226.103319-176.jar. But i notice there is a continues development and Apache PDFBox application published new version frequently. In the officials’ side I can see pdfbox-app-2.0.0-******-182,183,184.jar in the following [URL](http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/). I try to get with the pdfbox-app-2.0.0-******-177,178,179,180,181.jars using pom.xml file, but no luck. Could you please help me to get pdfbox-app-2.0.0-******-177,178,179,180,181.jars.

Comment: Usually only the most recent SNAPSHOTs are kept available in a Maven repository. Most likely those older ones have been deleted (probably automatically).

Comment: oops... Is there are any other way to get those? I badly need this jars for my test.

Comment: You can try to find out which SVN versions have been used for a given SNAPSHOT and build a PDFBox version from that; maybe there is a list somewhere, or a tag copy, or some other hint.

Comment: Indeed, you'll have to build from source. In Netbeans, you can get old versions by pressing "Search" in the svn "Folders to checkout" dialog. I.e. this will help you find a number instead of HEAD for the edit field. Don't know about other IDEs.

But I wonder why would you need old versions? I don't know of any recent regressions. Or do you suspect that there is one, and need the old versions to verify your theory?

Answer (score 2):

> Could you please help me to get pdfbox-app-2.0.0-**-177,178,179,180,181.jars.

No, no one could (except in the case the source repository were tagged for every snapshot, or you are so lucky to find somebody who have saved that specific version).

You should work with public repository, but if you need a not yet published functionality you could work with snapshot repository. In such a case you have to **be aware you are using an unstable**, rapidly-evolving, version so if your program works today it might not work tomorrow because the code has evolved: in general **this "problem" is a wanted behavior** when working with unstable versions.

In fact that problem notifies you that you are counting on a functionality that will not exists in the future at the same way as it existed in your used (old) version, and **the earlier you discover the error the better your are able to change your work** without too much pain.

In order to work with a snapshot repository add (in your case):

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ApacheSnapshot</id>
      <name>Apache Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

then add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

More generally speaking working effectively  with `SNAPSHOT` is to be intended in the context of a development process where developer teams communicate and project managers are in charge of making deadlines respected.